# Which clock should be used for inter process communication in linux?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, clock

I have implemented two single thread process A & B with two msg queue [separate queue for send and receive].  Process A will send a message to B and wait for reply in the receive queue.

I want to send a time-stamp from process A to process B. If process B receives the message after 10 second, i want to send a Error string from process B to A.

Accuracy should be in milliseconds.

In process A i used ,

```
  struct timespec   msg_dispatch_time;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &msg_dispatch_time);
  :
  :
  add_timestamp_in_msg(msg, msg_dispatch_time);
  :
  if (msgsnd(msqid, msg, sizeof(msg), msgflg) == -1)
      perror("msgop: msgsnd failed");
```

In process B,

```
  struct timespec   msg_dispatch_time;
  struct timespec  msg_receive_time;
  :
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &msg_received_time);
  :
  if( !(time_diff(msg_received_time, msg_dispatch_time) >= 10 ))
      msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, msg_flag)
  else
  {
      /*send the error string.*/
      //msgsnd(msgid,)
  }
```

My question is,

1) How to write a time_diff function here with millisecond accuracy to compare against 10 seconds?

```
   if( !(time_diff(msg_received_time, msg_dispatch_time) >= 10 ))



    /********Existing time diff code******************/
  long int time_diff (struct timeval time1, struct timeval time2)
  {
      struct timeval diff, 

      if (time1.tv_usec < time2.tv_usec) {
          time1.tv_usec += 1000000;
          time1.tv_sec--;
      }
      diff.tv_usec = time1.tv_usec - time2.tv_usec;
      diff.tv_sec = time1.tv_sec - time2.tv_sec;    
      return diff.tv_sec; //return the diff in second
  }
```

2) Is clock_gettime is fine to use across process in the same system?

Comment: `enum { NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000 };
void sub_timespec(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2, struct timespec *td)
{
    td->tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
    else if (td->tv_sec < 0 && td->tv_nsec > 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
}`

Comment: Check `timeval_subtract`  in http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

Comment: @NulledPointer: `timeval_subtract()` is for `struct timeval` rather than `struct timespec`, isn't it?  But the concepts can certainly be applied to the other type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to keep using the `struct timespec` type, then I recommend using a `difftime()` equivalent for `struct timespec` type, i.e.

```
double difftimespec(const struct timespec after, const struct timespec before)
{
    return (double)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)
         + (double)(after.tv_nsec - before.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}
```

However, I think there exists a better option for your overall use case.

If you are satisfied for your program to work till year 2242, you could use a 64-bit signed integer to hold the number of nanoseconds since Epoch. For binary messages, it is a much easier format to handle than `struct timespec`. Essentially:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef  int64_t     nstime;
#define  NSTIME_MIN  INT64_MIN
#define  NSTIME_MAX  INT64_MAX

nstime nstime_realtime(void)
{
    struct timespec  ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts))
        return NSTIME_MIN;

    return ((nstime)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000)
         + (nstime)ts.tv_nsec;
}

double nstime_secs(const nstime ns)
{
    return (double)ns / 1000000000.0;
}

struct timespec nstime_timespec(const nstime ns)
{
    struct timespec  ts;

    if (ns < 0) {
        ts.tv_sec = (time_t)(ns / -1000000000);
        ts.tv_nsec = -(long)((-ns) % 1000000000);
        if (ts.tv_nsec < 0L) {
            ts.tv_sec--;
            ts.tv_nsec += 1000000000L;
        }
    } else {
        ts.tv_sec = (time_t)(ns / 1000000000);
        ts.tv_nsec = (long)(ns % 1000000000);
    }
}
```

You can add and substract `nstime` timestamps any way you wish, and they are suitable for binary storage, too (byte order (aka endianness) issues notwithstanding).

(Note that the code above is untested, and I consider it public domain/CC0.)

---

Using `clock_gettime()` is fine. Both `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` are system-wide, i.e. should report the exact same results in different processes, if executed at the same physical moment.

`CLOCK_REALTIME` is available in all POSIXy systems, but `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is optional. Both are immune to daylight savings time changes. Incremental NTP adjustments affect both. Manual changes to system time by an administrator only affect `CLOCK_REALTIME`. The epoch for `CLOCK_REALTIME` is currently Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00, but it is unspecified for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Personally, I recommend using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,)`, because then your application can talk across processes in a cluster, not just on a local machine; cluster nodes may use different epochs for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.